# How to find mean of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the mean of each column, across all rows, given a set of data. I've opened the csv file using `sata = np.genfromtxt('movieRatingsDeidentified.csv',delimiter=',')`, and am currently trying to find the mean of each column across all rows using `D1 = numpy.nanmean(sata,axis=0)`however I'm getting an error message saying that sata is not defined, and is also not showing up in my variable explorer. It's incredibly frustrating as I have relatively little experience in programming and have only started using Spyder a few weeks ago.

Comment: I'm not familiar with spyder. But I think you haven't run your `sata = np.genfromtxt(...)` code before running `numpy.nanmean(...)` code.

Comment: Not enough information in your post but if you are getting a NameError then something might have happened during the `genfromtxt` execution or most likely `sata` is not within the scope of the `.nanmean` statement.  Please read [mre] and provide one. We also like to see the complete Traceback if there is one (formatted as code).

Comment: @Yevhen Kuzmovych I have run my `sata = np.genfromtxt('movieRatingsDeidentified.csv',delimiter=',')` code before running the nanmean, and am getting the following output:  Line #3200 (got 209 columns instead of 211), Line #3201 (got 209 columns instead of 211), etc.

Comment: Scope is an important thing to understand, you may have to review these periodically till it really sinks in : [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html) , [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects)

Comment: If some of the lines in the file are missing *columns* - [https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html#using-missing-and-filling-values](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html#using-missing-and-filling-values)

Comment: The error messages suggest that you have different number of values in each row. I guess you can tell the genfromfile function to handle the missing values as nan.

Comment: Your question title is a little misleading.

Comment: The basic point is that you can't move on to the `nanmean` command without first resolving the `genfromtxt` one.  And that apparently depends on cleaning up your `csv` file so it has a consistent number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it says that sata is not defined, you are most likely not opening the file properly. My guess is that you are not in the proper folder path. Use the package **os** to find your current working folder and change to the appropriate folder. The function `os.getcwd()` will show you in which folder you are and `os.chdir("your/target/folder")` will lead you to the appropriate folder. Alternatively, instead of passing only the file name to `np.genfromtxt`you can pass the full path.
Also, unless you have missing values (NaN) in your dataset, you should probably use the regular `np.mean` instead of `np.nanmean`.

Comment: If this were the case wouldn't it produce a File Not Found error? I didn't see anything in the post about that.